# Changes to the HTML or CSS files have no affect

Tags: html, css, tomcat

I am writing a web project in eclipse with tomcat. Every time I write an HTML ,run it once and then change it, I don't see the difference. 
The build automatically is checked. The only thing that worked is to delete the server every time and make a new one, and it doesn't work every time. 
thanks!

Comment: Is it saved in browser cache?

Comment: @Selaron has a point. Did you try refreshing the page in you browser using `Ctrl+Shift+R` or whatever your browser needs to refresh without cache?

Comment: If you turned off eclipse "Build automatically" or did not start Tomcat in debug mode, Eclipse might not deploy changed files either. Not sure if this is true for static HTML files tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use force refresh of the browser cltr + shift + R,